# AngularJS, ng-include not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this ng-include not work but the browser console is empty

```
<div class='pianificazioneOpertion-module'>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div  ng-if="step == false" ng-incude src="'pianificazioneModule/patrimonioNonFinanziarioModule/pianificazioneOperationModule/step.html'"></div>
    <div  ng-if="step == true && operation.tipologia=='5'" ng-include src="'pianificazioneModule/patrimonioNonFinanziarioModule/pianificazioneOperationModule/venditaDonazione.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `ng-include="'pianifi...`. The `src` attribute is only applicable on the `<ng-include>` element version of the directive

Comment: What happens if you remove the ng-if statements? Have you verified that the path is correct?

Comment: Why are you using single quotes inside double quotes for `src` at ng-include?

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador because it's required

Comment: @Mr.White yes the path is correct and if i remove the ng-if statements 
the result is always that

Comment: @Phil  the result is always that

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ng-if` and `ng-include` in that way. Use this instead.

```
<div class='pianificazioneOpertion-module'>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div  ng-if="step == false">
      <ng-incude src="'pianificazioneModule/patrimonioNonFinanziarioModule/pianificazioneOperationModule/step.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="step == true && operation.tipologia=='5'">
      <ng-include src="'pianificazioneModule/patrimonioNonFinanziarioModule/pianificazioneOperationModule/venditaDonazione.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is because ng-include is a tag itself.

Check Angular docs for ngInclude https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

**UPDATE**

Check this:

> In addition, the browser's Same Origin Policy and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy may further restrict whether the template is successfully loaded. For example, ngInclude won't work for cross-domain requests on all browsers and for file:// access on some browsers.

From Angular Docs. If you're trying to execute your code from `file://` instead of `http://` (running from node server, by example) it won't work because CORS policy may block it.

Run from Apache/nginx/Node Http server.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Maybe there is a problem with the controller.